# Decoding Ciphertext by Brute Force

Tags: python, encryption, brute-force

```
def rotated(n: int):
    '''Returns a rotated letter if parameter is greater than 26'''
    ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    if n>= 26:
        n %= 26
    return ALPHABET[n:26] + ALPHABET[:n]
assert rotated(0) == 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
assert rotated(26) == 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

The function above is to reset the alphabet if the integer given is equal to greater than 26 (so the letter z with key 1 would equate to a).

```
def Caesar_decrypt(text: str, key: int) -> str:
    '''Returns a decryption of parameter text and key'''
    text = text.lower()
    key_to_zero = str.maketrans(rotated(key),rotated(0))
    return text.translate(key_to_zero)
assert Caesar_decrypt('Cat', 29) == Caesar_decrypt('Cat', 3)
assert Caesar_decrypt('Good night', 0) == 'good night'
```

Caesar_decrypt then takes the rotated function to decrypt a given text string with a key given. However, I'm trying to decrypt a given text WITHOUT a key, which would be my next function: Caesar_break.

```
word = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
dictionary = word.readlines()
def Caesar_break(code: str) -> str:
    alist = []
    for x in range(26):
        a = Caesar_decrypt(code, x)
        alist += a
    for i in dictionary:
        if i in alist:
            return i
```

***Note: wordlist.txt is just a document with all dictionary words. Refer to http://www.ics.uci.edu/~kay/wordlist.txt. So I was wondering why when I tested out the Caesar_break code, the shell window doesn't return anything. How can I fix the code? Thanks!

If my words are confusing, this is an example of how the function is supposed to work:

```
Caesar_decrypt('mjqqt', 5) == 'hello'
```

Using Caesar_break, the above assertion would look like:

```
Caesar_break('mjqqt') == 'hello'
```

(both equal to 'hello')

In other words, I need Caesar_break to decode a message WITHOUT the 5 there.

Comment: forgive me if I am just being really stupid right now, but I have never seen explicit parameter/return type declarations in python...

Comment: other than that, you have indentation problems inside of `Caesar_break`. i assume the `for x in range(26):` is wrongly indented? also, you do realize that `wordlist.txt` is a massive file so the `for i in dictionary` loop will likely run for a long time....

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally added four spaces when pasting the code onto stackoverflow, thanks. As for the wordlist file, is there a way for the code to work without looping for that much time then?

Comment: Convention in python, recommends to use lowercased names for methods `caesar_break`, even if it corresponds to a personal name.

Comment: @RNar New in python 3.5, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/.

Answer (score 0):

Not so different to your version, I've just changed few things, if the word is found inside the `for-in` then we return the word. Note that I uncapitalized the methods to fulfill the convention.

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as words:
    dictionary = frozenset(map(str.strip, words))

def caesar_break(code: str):
    for x in range(26):
        word = caesar_decrypt(code, x)

        if word in dictionary:
            return word
```

Comment: Hm, the shell also returns nothing when I try this.

Comment: @RamonHallan, Is that word in your `dictionary`?, is it possible that you didn't parse the `dictionary` properly?

Comment: A'asia is in the dictionary, yes, but when I tried it again copying your exact code, it didn't return anything again.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto: `readlines` doesn't strip newlines, and it gives a `list` that will be expensive to check over and over. Change to `with open('wordlist.txt') as f:`, `dictionary = frozenset(map(str.strip, f))` and it will both strip whitespace (including newlines) and produce a deduped, fast membership check `frozenset` of the words for lookup.

Comment: I found that your code works, but only for the first word of the message. Is there a way around this? For example "hello comrade" in encrypted form only prints out hello.

Comment: It just needs a slight modification, Is `code`  composed by any amount of words separated by spaces?